# How do I keep my active window under others with XMouse in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, xmouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make mouse in Windows 7 act the same as Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/76315/how-to-make-mouse-in-windows-7-act-the-same-as-windows-xp)

I'm a big fan of [XMouse functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmouse) and have been using [True X-Mouse Gizmo](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/) for  ages. It has both the xmouse-functionality as well as *not* putting the active window on top. I can't live without these things.

I just installed Windows 7 on a computer. To my great surprise they have implemented the XMouse functionality (in something called ease of access center). But I'm still missing the option to let my active window stay underneath other windows.

Does this setting exist in Windows 7, or must I download something? What in such a case?

What I'm looking for is sloppy focus for Windows 7.

Comment: https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  Here's the answer.

[How to make xmouse in Windows 7 act the same as in XP](https://superuser.com/questions/76315/how-to-make-mouse-in-windows-7-act-the-same-as-windows-xp)