# Keyboard shortcut to make active window the window at the position of the cursor

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, macros, hotkeys

In Windows, I want to enter a key command and have whatever window is currently beneath the cursor be made the active window. Is there a piece of software that makes this possible?

Comment: What is the OS?  Are you familliar with the constant activating of windows for which the mouse is over at the time http://superuser.com/questions/76315/how-to-make-mouse-in-windows-7-act-the-same-as-windows-xp  It does not ever work for me, but it is good to know what it is, and how it works.

Comment: I'm currently using Windows 7, but I'd like it to work for XP as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style of mouse-window interaction you are looking for is called *focus follows mouse pointer*, and on Windows it's also called [x-mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmouse) or window tracking.

- Windows XP: I'd recommend [Microsoft's Tweak UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweak_UI), and the X-Mouse settings there.
- Windows 7: There are settings to enable it in the *Ease of Access Center* (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), but to tweak the delay I recommend my small open source utility [X-Mouse Controls](https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/).

[image: Main window of X-Mouse Controls]

> [X-Mouse Controls](https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/): Windows utility to enable or disable active window tracking, raising and also the delay in milliseconds. This is known as x-mouse behavior or focus follows mouse.

Window raising is discouraged. A delay of 100-250 ms should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply click on it? I think it is both faster and more time sufficient than any other solution. (I wanted to write this as a comment, but unfortunately I don't have the right amount of reputation)

Comment: The reason is I will sometimes think I'm in one window, start typing, and realize I'm in another window. Since my hands are already on the keyboard, it is much easier for me to hit some hotkeys, and continue typing than reach for the mouse, mouse up to the top of the window. and click.

Comment: Well, in that case why don't you look at your monitor, then hit Alt+Tab and once you get to your desired window, start typing? You could also try Alt+Shift+Tab.

Comment: I should also mention that I have come along such programs that assign hot keys to each open window in Windows, but to be honest I don't remember their names at the moment.

Comment: I like Alt+Tab but I have lots of windows open so it isn't always very efficient