# Make window active on taskbar icon hover

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I want to make a window come to the front after hovering over it, or its thumbnail, in the taskbar.

Any idea how?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have researched and tried so far. We will try to help from that point. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mouse in Windows 7 act the same as Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/76315/how-to-make-mouse-in-windows-7-act-the-same-as-windows-xp)

Answer (score -2):

Please try this:
*Ease of Access Center* -> *Make the mouse easier to use* -> *Make it easier to manage windows*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this doesn't help.
This sets any window you hover over to active and bring them to the front.
It doesn't bring a window to the front when hovering over it's icon in the task bar.