# Is there an easy way to emulate Linux Mouse behavior on Windows/Mac

Tags: windows, linux, mac, mouse

I predominantly use Ubuntu at home, which means I am used to "highlight 'copies' and center click 'pastes'" (I believe this is true for all X-windows-sever machines, but I don't know).  Unfortunately, that is not the behavior on the machines I use at work (I have a Mac and Win 7.).  Is there an application which would let me imitate this mouse behavior for either of those OS's?

Comment: You're asking specifically about the paste buffer, and not the "focus under mouse" (which is a classic Unix mouse behavior, but most newer window managers don't use it), correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 7, see the answer here: [How do I keep my active window under others with XMouse in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56133/how-do-i-keep-my-active-window-under-others-with-xmouse-in-windows-7) The [True X-Mouse Gizmo](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/) works well for this on Windows XP, but apparently Windows 7 needs other tweeks. I don't know how to do this on a Mac.